# how to download and save image get from facebook link in yii project

Tags: php, facebook, yii

i am using yii boilerplate and set /pimages as web alias for backend images directory , i am using this alias for getting frontend images 
Now my problem statement is , i want to copy image of specific user when use login my site my site using facebook , i am using below code to get image of the user .

First method using file get content is

```
 $facebookimage = "http://graph.facebook.com/" . $facebook_id . "/picture/?type=large";
            $image =  @file_put_contents(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/pimages/user/' , file_get_contents($facebookimage));
```

and other method using curl is below but i really cant understand this that why the author is using myimg123.jpg in example

```
 $path = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/pimages/user/';  // your saving path
            $headers = get_headers($profile_Image, 1);
            $profile_Image = $headers['Location'];
            $ch = curl_init($profile_Image);
            $fp = fopen($path . $userImage, 'wb');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use curl with the following option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```